# How to retrieve an image found on google having just the cached url?

Tags: image, url, google-search

Some time ago (about a year and half) I found an image on google, having the following url in the search engine archive:

[http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQhMUKiipOilBrW3xjrD7FCuQ4M9jCEWyQXmv0d3-pgHIVeYHJwTHvkW-1_yg](http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3aANd9GcQhMUKiipOilBrW3xjrD7FCuQ4M9jCEWyQXmv0d3-pgHIVeYHJwTHvkW-1_yg)

Now you can see it can't be found (1x1 pixel image means that).

Is there a way to decode the tbn value and recover the original image name or query or anything helpful to find another copy of the same image?

Comment: I don't know definitely, however, I would suggest that if the image was a cached image and now isn't accessible that it has been deleted in order to make room. Therefore, you wouldn't be able to find it anywhere unless you had previously downloaded it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. That's the whole point of it. When [a user requests an image removal](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663694) or Google decides that for some reason an image must be removed, then the image is being deleted from the Google cache, so you can't find the image because it got deleted.

Edit: I understand that you reaaally want to get back that image but it is deleted from the Google cache. There is no way to recover it using info in the tbn value.

If you know someone who may have recently requested that image through his browser, you can search with the url in their browser's cache, [using this method](http://lifehacker.com/5477287/recover-recently-deleted-web-content-via-your-browsers-cache).

Comment: maybe one could revert the cached url to the original url, in order to find a copy somewhere else...?